# Creating a custom uibarbuttonitem, button image wrong

Tags: image, ios6, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to create a custom UiBarButtonItem. When I build the project on IOS simulator, the custom buttons proportions are all wrong. I have tried different sizes of image and they all don't work. What am I doing wrong?

Example

```
 UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebookbutton4.png"]  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];

 authButton =
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                target:self
                                action:@selector(authButtonAction:)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = authButton;
```

The current image is 74 x 46 pixels, resolution 952 pixels per inch. Im having difficulty trying to set the resolution properly, i'm using iDraw for mac. What resolution should the image be?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what it looks like in your simulator?

Comment: Hello, here are some screenshots, hopefully!

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/103621772/screenshot2.tiff https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/103621772/iphoneshot.tiff

Answer (score 1):

[Here's Apple's guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) - 20x20 points so try 40x40px 72DPI for your retina @2x, 20x20px for normal.